# Computing the gradient orientations using only the gradient magnitudes image

Tags: python, gradient, edge-detection, deconvolution, sobel

How can I compute the gradient orientations image using the gradient magnitudes image — is there a technique to inverse the convolutional step of the input image with a Sobel filter to compute the two gradients directions images (Ix and Iy)?

Answer (score 1):

This problem corresponds to a so-called Eikonal differential equation, which can be solved numerically: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eikonal_equation#2D_approximation_on_a_Cartesian_grid.

Don't do that.